# TitleWindow position on screenreen in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, action, flex3

I would like to position the window on the screen as TitleWindow image attached to an applicat![enter image description here][1]ion because I'm using is necessary that he is to be called exactly that position. How could he do?

http://www.techall.com.br/Doubt/TitleWindow.jpg

Comment: Your English is very confusing! You want to place a TitleWindow inside a flash application? In the image, the light grey is flash?

Comment: sorry I'm from Brazil and I'm using google translator to mount the question. I'm using Flex 3 and I have a screen that I call TitleWindows flex but it appears centered on the screen that I would be centralized but appears on the top screen.

Comment: my aplication is call this: var popup_CADASTRO = new CADASTRO;
PopUpManager.addPopUp(popup_CADASTRO ,this,true);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popup_CADASTRO );

Comment: Ah, ok Eduardo. Verifique abaixo a minha resposta e veja se é isto que procurava. Se não perceber alguma coisa é só dizer :)

Answer (score 0):

After creating a TitleWindow you can set its position just by setting the x/y values.

```
var popup_CADASTRO = new CADASTRO;
PopUpManager.addPopUp(popup_CADASTRO ,this,true);

popup_CADASTRO.x = 20; // x position where you want to put the window
popup_CADASTRO.y = 40; // y position where you want to put the window
```

You don't need to do the PopUpManager.centerPopUp.

Comment: Fantastic that was it, thank you very much, I am very grateful for the attention, do not know if you are from Brazil but the translation was perfect!

Fantástico era isso mesmo, muito obrigado, fico muito grato pela atenção, não sei se você é do Brazil mas a tradução ficou perfeita!